# How do I set my Web Form in the jQuery Modal Dialog and use this?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

I have a ASP.NET application for list all search User in a `ListView` in "BenutzerListe.aspx". A client user can select a User and show that user's Properties in an extra Web Form, named "benutzer.aspx". In "Benutzer.aspx", the user can change these Properties.

I want show this informations, not in a second Web Form, but in a Dialog, create by jQuery. I hear that I can input my "Benutzer.aspx" in the dialog.

How I can do this?

My Idea:

[image: screenshot with a mock up of the idea]

aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="~/BenutzerListe.aspx.cs" Inherits="BenutzerListe.BenutzerListe" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="Scripte/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

     <link href="~/App_Theme/BenutzerListeStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />

    <style type="text/css">
        #SuchTabelle
        {
            width: 587px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#Button2").click(function (event) {

                //How I open a Dialog with Benutzer.aspx

            });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div class="header">
        <table id="SuchTabelle" runat="server" border="0">

            <tr>
                <th><asp:Label ID="id_SearchUser" runat="server" Text="lblSearchUser"></asp:Label></th>
                <th><asp:TextBox ID="txtBenutzer" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox></th>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><asp:Label ID="id_location" runat="server" Text="lblLocation"></asp:Label></th>
                <th><asp:DropDownList ID="dropWerk" runat="server" Width="250px" /></th>
                <th><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Suchen" 
                                onclick="btnBenutzerSuchen_Click" Width="219px" /></th>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <div id="bild">
            <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Theme/lw_logo.jpg" Height="58px" 
                Width="277px" />
        </div>

        <div id="meldung">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMeldung"></asp:Label>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="bodyList">


        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="myListView">

        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="UserTable" runat="server" border="0" width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr style="background-color:#E5E5FE" class="TableClass">
                    <th id="th1" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBenutzer" runat="server" >id_Benutzer</asp:LinkButton></th>
                    <th id="th2" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkemail" runat="server" >id_Email</asp:LinkButton></th>
                    <th id="th3" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkVorname" runat="server" >id_Vorname</asp:LinkButton></th>
                    <th id="th4" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkNachname" runat="server" >id_Nachname</asp:LinkButton></th>
                    <th id="th5" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTelefon" runat="server" >id_Telefon</asp:LinkButton></th>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server" id="ItemPlaceholder">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>

            <tr class="TableClass">    
                <td align="left" ><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("Benutzername") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("eMail") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("Vorname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("Nachname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label5" Text='<%# Eval("Telefonnummer") %>' runat="server" /></td>

              <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label6" Text='<%# Eval("GUID") %>' runat="server" Visible="False" /></td>

            </tr>

        </ItemTemplate>

        <AlternatingItemTemplate>

            <tr class="TableClass"> 

                <td align="left" ><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("Benutzername") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("eMail") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("Vorname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("Nachname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label5" Text='<%# Eval("Telefonnummer") %>' runat="server" /></td>

                <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label6" Text='<%# Eval("GUID") %>' runat="server" Visible="False" /></td>

            </tr>

        </AlternatingItemTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>

        <br />
        <br />

    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Each time you've written "WinForm" here, do you mean "WebForm"?  Or are you actually trying to mix Windows Client application Forms with an ASP.NET web application?

Comment: Ah, ok.  Could you show the relevant markup for your page?  Have you tried anything so far?  It's always nice to show your work up to this point (even if your attempt have been unsuccessful).  See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), especially the section under "Do your homework".

Answer (score 0):

Try if this helps:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536759(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could do something as simple with the [JQUERY UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/):

In your page:

```
<div id="dialog">
<iframe src="Benutzer.aspx"></iframe>
</div>
```

In your jquery function:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#Button2").click(function (event) {

               $( "#dialog" ).dialog();

            });
```